# Exit from a "Find" infinite loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a Do Loop with Find to replace "Hello" with "Hi" inside column A of Sheet1, but only if the string "XYZ" is not in the same row of column B.

When Find does not replace "Hello", because in column B there is "XYZ", we enter an infinite loop since FindNext always finds "Hello" in column 1

It is possible to avoid infinite loop without making **Loop While** very complicated?

[Please see this image of columns in sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXOQL.jpg)

```
Sub CallMask()
    Call Masks("Hello", "XYZ")
End Sub

Sub Masks(sMask_I As String, sNoReplace_I As String)
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
        Dim CellToReplace As Range
        Set CellToReplace = .Find(What:=sMask_I, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, Lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not CellToReplace Is Nothing Then
            Dim InitialAddress As String
            InitialAddress = CellToReplace.Address
            Dim MaskRow As Long
            Dim Mask As String
            On Error Resume Next
            Do
                MaskRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(sMask_I, _
                  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & Rows.Count), 0)
                Mask = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & MaskRow).Value2
                If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(CellToReplace.Row, 2) <> sNoReplace_I Then
                    CellToReplace.Value2 = Replace(CellToReplace.Value2, sMask_I, Mask)
                End If
                Set CellToReplace = .FindNext(CellToReplace)
            Loop While Not CellToReplace Is Nothing And CellToReplace.Address _
              <> InitialAddress
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could check with a `COUNTIF()` to see if "XYZ" is in the same row, and work from there?

Comment: The code that I have uploaded is a simplification of the real one. It would not be possible to use COUNTIF () in my real code. Thanks Bruce

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CallMask()
    Call Masks("Hello", "XYZ", "Hi")
End Sub

Sub Masks(sMask_I As String, sNoReplace_I As String, Replacement As String)
    Dim C As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each C In .Range("A1", "A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
            If C Like "*" & sMask_I & "*" And C.Offset(0, 1) <> sNoReplace_I Then
                C.Replace sMask_I, Replacement
            End If
        Next C
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Damian, your code works very well but uses the For Next loop and is very slow. That's why I want to use the Find method

Comment: Malamare For Next loop is the fastest when working with cells. If you want it faster you could do it with arrays, that would be way faster.

Comment: For faster performance, copy the range into an array, work on the array, and then return the array to the range. Based on your comment, you must be working with a lot of rows - so this will make a noticeable difference.

Comment: @Malamare `For Each` would be the fastest way to iterate the cells in a `Range`, since a `Range` is essentially a collection of `Range` objects, and object collections are best iterated with `For Each`. A `For...Next` loop is much faster for iterating arrays - in any case, any code that interacts with cells in a loop will be much slower than it needs to be. Consider copying the cell values into an array, and using a `For` loop to iterate the array instead; modify the array in-place, then replace all cells with the array contents in a single worksheet-writing operation. *That* will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

When using Find() in a loop it's typically easier to abstract that out into a separate method:

```
Sub CallMask()
    Masks "Hello", "XYZ"
End Sub

Sub Masks(sMask_I As String, sNoReplace_I As String)
    Dim matches As Collection, c

    Set matches = FindAll(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1), sMask_I)

    For Each c In matches
        If c.Offset(0, 1) <> sNoReplace_I Then
            c.Value = Replace(c.Value, sMask_I, c.Offset(0, 3).Value)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub

'return all matches as a collection
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! your code works well for me. Only change "c.Offset (0, 3) .value" by the reference to "Hi". if not Offset returns "" except in the first row

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with arrays as suggested by Damian, AJD and Mathieu. It is the fastest code.

Times for 1600 rows are:

1. My new code with arrays: 8 ms
2. Damian code with For Next: 132 ms
3. The Code with "separate method" of Tim Williams: 402 ms
4. My first code with Find: 511 ms

This is the new code:

```
Sub CallMask()
    Call Masks("Hello", "XYZ")
End Sub

Sub Masks(ByVal sMask_I As String, ByVal sNoReplace_I As String)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim ArrayRangeToMask As Variant
        ArrayRangeToMask = .Range("A1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)

        Dim MaskRow As Long
        Dim Mask As String
        MaskRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(sMask_I, .Range("C1:C" & Rows.Count), 0)
        Mask = .Range("D" & MaskRow).Value2

        Dim RowMasking As Long
        For RowMasking = 1 To UBound(ArrayRangeToMask)
            If InStr(ArrayRangeToMask(RowMasking, 1), sMask_I) And _
              ArrayRangeToMask(RowMasking, 2) <> sNoReplace_I Then
                ArrayRangeToMask(RowMasking, 1) = _
                  Replace(ArrayRangeToMask(RowMasking, 1), sMask_I, Mask)
            End If
        Next RowMasking

        .Range("A1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row) = ArrayRangeToMask
    End With

End Sub
```